# \setarrowdefault gives error when using chemfig

Tags: arrows, chemfig

I have a problem, I wnat to change the *arrow tip style* while using `\chemfig`. I've read to use the command `\setarrowdefault` but it gives the error "Undefined control sequence". Where do you think is the problem? The code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections, patterns, snakes, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\setchemfig{atom sep=0.75}
    \chemnameinit{\chemfig{C(-[:120]H_3C)(=[:-120]O)-C(-[:60]OH)(=[:-60]O)}}
    \setarrowdefault{15,1.5,red,thick}
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{C(-[:120]H_3C)(=[:-120]O)-C(-[:60]OH)(=[:-60]O)}}{Piruvato}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{NADH}}{}
    \+
    \chemfig{H^+}
    \arrow(.mid east--.mid west)
    \chemname{\chemfig{CH(-[:120]H_3C)(-[:-120]HO)-C(-[:60]OH)(=[:-60]O)}}{Acido Lattico}
    \+
    \chemname{\chemfig{NAD^+}}{}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just found the answer:

Comment: Welcome at TeX.SE ! // Great :) Please share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer. `chemfig` changed and now it takes only:

```
\setchemfig{atom sep=0.75,
            arrow style=-to,...}
```

To do everything.